Is the meaning of a sign the effect it has on your mind?
Is the meaning of something identifiable or reducible to the motion or effect it causes on the mind that interprets it?
For example, the meaning of a photograph could be said to be the nostalgic emotion it induces in the one who views it, and the things it makes that person think. The meaning of a word could be said to be the mental pattern that arises upon reading the word. The meaning of an actionable piece of information could be said to be the change in the plan that arises in the mind of the planner upon analyzing that information.
So in this way we reduce meaning to cause and effect, which is something empirically observable. This is why such an approach is desirable, if it can be made to work.
There is one detail worth mentioning, which is that sometimes an interpreter will fail to apprehend the correct meaning of a sign. For example: they may be reading a map which they are mistakenly holding upside down. How could this happen if the meaning is just the effect on the interpreter's mind? To account for this case, we must amend the previous idea. We can say that there are many possible cognitive methods that the interpreter might apply to process the sign, and some methods are more useful (in general, or on average) for achieving the interpreter's goals than others. The correct meaning of the sign can now be described as the effect the sign would have upon the mind of the interpreter, provided that they applied generally useful methods. In the upside-down map example, this allows us to say that the correct meaning of the map to the interpreter is the effect on their mind it would have if they held the map right side up and applied generally useful orienteering skills.
Is there any serious, unsolvable problem with this approach?

If a cartoon with strobic light causes a seizure,  should we say that the cartoon means seizure? If a picture causes laughter, should we say the picture means laughter? What if the same picture induces another to cry instead? Does the picture now mean both laughter and weeping?

@JD - I would indeed say all this. "Meaning" is always relative to some agent(s) to wich the message/sign is meaningful (so yes, effect on their mind or on their behavior), and then it's relative to the task at hand/whatever the agent wanted to do with the map/the wider context. It's possible to just focus on certain parts of that whole process, but an empirical theory can only be based on the approach sketched by @ causative. In Charles Pierce's theory we have sign/thought/object (where object really can be anything - in particular, it's really the way signs are used).

@JD - It also is not so relevant what we "should" say or not (should, apparently meaning: this and this doesn't completely conform to some of our preconceptions about "meaning"?). What is relevant is what we can do with a theory like that. For instance, will it help to understand animal communication better? Will it help to develop better dialog systems? Does it make us understand better how communication actually works? Can the theory be integrated with other theories about social processes, etc.

Meaning is also intersubjective, social. This is the reason why we have to learn to "read" symbols (the map example).

Jesus says, "Let the dead bury their own dead." The meaning of "dead" changes in the context of the sentence so we call it equivocal.
